# Customize the drop down list in html

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have defined a drop down list as follows. I am using it on Android with phonegap. I want to customize the drop down list from within the html. I want to appear it as a dropdown without it coming to the front. Is it possible?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Language.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function dropdown(){  var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text="3";
optn.value="3";
drp.add(optn);
} 


</script>
</head>

<body onload="dropdown();">
<div id="main3"></div>

<form><select id = "numberlist"><option>12</option><option>24</option><option>36</option></select></form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The dropdown is modified with your code but What do you mean by "without it coming to the front"? Do you mean that the dropdown shouldn't get the focus?

Comment: yes it gets focused when you try to select an item from the dropdown list. I want to view the list items on the screen itself without getting focused. Is that possible?

Comment: You could create your own drop-down list, rather than using a form.

Comment: Thanks maddjak will it enable me to have a dropdown list which doesnot get focused?